# yii2 pick time from datetime

Tags: php, datetime, yii2

I want to know how to pick the time format from datetime in yii2.

So if there is code like this

```
$model->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 hours'));
and the result would be 2018-05-08 23:36:21
```

how can I extract the time only? so the result is only `23:36:21`

I already tried using code below

```
date("H:i:s", strtotime('-30 minutes'));
```

but I only got like `00:30:00`

Is there something wrong with the code?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `date("H:i:s", strtotime('-30 minutes'));` returns the time value half an hour ago for the timezone which is set in PHP settings. What value do you want to get?

Comment: do you want to extract the time only from a given string `2018-05-08 23:36:21` or add interval?

Answer (score 1):

if you have the string `2018-05-08 23:36:21` and want to extract time, you can follow the following methods

## Using `php:date()` function

Remove `-30m` from the time when you format the date

```
echo date('H:i:s',strtotime('2018-05-08 23:36:21 -30 minutes'));
```

## `Using DateTime Object`

The method [**`sub()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) can subtract from the time and output the remaining time using `$dateTimeObj->format()`.

```
$date1=new \DateTime('2018-05-08 23:36:21');
$date1->sub(new \DateInterval('PT30M'));
echo $date1->format('H:i:s');
```